# Design pattern for declaring that class property expects a specific class or subclass

Tags: php, design-patterns

I want to declare a class property with a type that expects to be a specific class or subclass. So I need something like the following (hopefully the code is self-explanitory):

```php
class LibraryClass
{
    private static string $utilityClass = LibraryUtilityClass::class;

    public static function setUtilityClass(string $utilityClass)
    {
        if ( is_a($utilityClass, LibraryUtilityClass::class) ) {
            self::$utilityClass = $utilityClass;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class MyUtilityClass extends LibraryUtilityClass{}
class FooBar{}

LibraryClass::setUtilityClass(MyUtilityClass::class); // returns true
LibraryClass::setUtilityClass(FooBar::class); //returns false (but IDE doesn't catch it)
```

I would really LOVE to do something more like this instead:

```php
class LibraryClass
{
    public static [LibraryUtilityClassOrChildOf] $utilityClass = LibraryUtilityClass::class;
}
...
LibraryClass::$utilityClass = LibraryUtilityClass::class; // no issues
LibraryClass::$utilityClass = MyUtilityClass::class; // no issues
LibraryClass::$utilityClass = FooBar::class; // throws a type mismatch error (IDE will highlight)
```

I'd imagine this pattern is not an unusual one. I just want to extend a utility that is used by some vendor class and let `LibraryClass` know I'd like to use my extension instead of the default.

**Does this pattern have a name, and how should it be done correctly?** The first option above will work, but seems error-prone, and I'd love for my IDE to tell me it's wrong before runtime. (Maybe there's a PHPDoc way of doing this.)

I'm stuck on **PHP 7.4**, so no PHP 8.0 goodness for me, though a PHP8 way of doing this would certainly be nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

You have the problems, because this design is bad itself.
So, to answer your question, there is **NO such language constructions**, and **NO way to make IDE check string for being a valid class name**, because it does not run your program on inspection and knows nothing about your string contents, so even phpDoc will not help.
Maybe, there's some tricky hack to achieve the result you wish, but it will be ugly code, that someday will make you suffer.

Better way to build it - just make `LibraryUtilityClass` a dependency for your `LibraryClass`.
You need to build an instance of `LibraryUtilityClass` or its child outside and pass it to the `LibraryClass` constructor. If you pass parent class typehint, you will be able to pass a child without any problem. And get rid of static property.

The best way, is to extend `LibraryUtilityClass` and make an interface for library features that you wish to use in your app. And pass this interface to `LibraryClass` instead of `LibraryUtilityClass`.

To manage your dependencies nicely - read about the DI (dependency injection). But maybe you know about it :)